# prepend ; before declaring a function

Tags: javascript

What is the purpose of declaring a function (an IIFE) like the following :

```
// note the leading ;
;(function (params) {
     //...
})(123)
```

My question is specifically about the leading `;`.

I found this in the [`semantic-ui`](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-LESS/blob/master/definitions/behaviors/api.js#L12) repository.